# Google PlayGames Login Problems .apk vs .abb

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have developed an app with Unity. There I installed Google Game Services and also created all the necessary successes and leader boards in the Developer Account, as well as I also activated saved games.

Now the following problem:

If I manually transfer the app as APK (.apk data) to the smartphone with a cable from my computer, everything works as planned. After the start of the app, a connection to game services is established and a previously uploaded score is made and open.

However, if I download the app via the website of my Coogle Developer Consolen Accounts as an alpha test phase (.abb data), then no connection to game services is sent and therefore no scorer storage is downloaded from the cloud. I added my testers to the lists and unlocked them for the Alpha phase.

I really didn't program anything else, but rather down and install the identical app in two different ways.

In the debug mode I was able to find that the functions
Playgames platform.activate ();
Instance.authenticate (process authentication);
What the signin status.Success will not be called if I download the app via the Playstore (alpha test phase).

Why does it happen?
Is the intention because of the alpha phase or is missing a setting in the developer account. I am at a loss, please help me.

Did I forget a setting in the Google Play Console?

Unity2021.3.33f1